# Why does this function run slower with CUDA vs parallel?

Tags: python, numba

Ive create a bilateral filter in python and added numba to(in theory) run it on the my GPU. Yet when I set the mode to CUDA its extremely slow and doesn't seem to use my graphics card at all while putting it into parallel makes it very fast. The best reason I have is that my function just isn't optimized to run on my GPU very well because it can't apply one function to all elements at once(because it requires the x and y coordinate to work). So my question is, why does this run slow with target set to CUDA?

```
@guvectorize([(float64[:,:], float64[:,:])],'(n,m)->(n,m)',target='cuda',nopython =True)
def apply_filter(img, filteredImage):

imh, imw = img.shape[:2]
radius = diameter // 2
hd = int((diameter - 1) / 2)

#print("starting work in cuda")
for h in prange(hd, imh - hd):
    for w in prange(hd, imw - hd):
        Wp = 0
        filteredPixel = 0
        startX = h
        startY = w
        for x in prange(0, diameter):
            for y in prange(0, diameter):

                currentX = startX - (radius - x)
                cureentY = startY - (radius - y)

                intensityDifferent = img[currentX][cureentY] - img[startX][startY]
                intensity = (1.0 / (2 * math.pi * (sIntesity ** 2)) * math.exp(- (intensityDifferent ** 2) / (2 * sIntesity ** 2)))
                distance = ((currentX-startX)**2 + (cureentY-startY)**2)**(1/2)
                smoothing = (1.0 / (2 * math.pi * (sSpace ** 2))) * math.exp(- (distance ** 2) / (2 * sSpace ** 2))
                weight =  intensity * smoothing;

                filteredPixel += img[currentX][cureentY] * weight
                Wp += weight

        filteredImage[h][w] = int(round(filteredPixel / Wp))
#print("done!")
```

Comment: Is it really supposed to be `@guvectorize`?

Comment: From my understanding, it should be as I'm passing in a array and want work done on it vs vectorize being just for scalars.

Comment: There is a `p` missing is what I meant.

Comment: Its possible Im missing something but https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/jit-compilation.html#numba.guvectorize is what Im using and it is not missing a p